# Can't solve a typeerror with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm pretty sure this is nothing but as I'm new with coding I'm struggling with this problem.
I'm trying to make my table navigable with arrows but when I use an arrow it just doesn't work. It seems to be because of a TypeError but I can't succeed to understand what's going wrong. If anyone could explain that would be great !

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VoctorR/a6hzmpx3/2/)

Problem seems to come from line 60.
This problem started with the fact I was using DataTable script. I then had these lines at the beginning of the js file :

```
// DataTable //
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable( {
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    fixedHeader: true,
    colReorder: true,
    stateSave: true,
});
```

But I wanted to remove that script to not depend about anything else (I'm learning by trying to do everything myself). So I tried to replace it with some vars, but unsuccessfully so far. My highlight function looked like this with DataTable :

```
        function highlight() { 
        document.querySelectorAll('.highlight-rc').forEach(col => col.classList.remove('highlight-rc'));            
        var colIdx = table.cell(c).index().column;
        $(table.cells().nodes()).removeClass('highlight-rc');
        $(table.column(colIdx).nodes()).addClass('highlight-rc');
        currCell.removeClass('highlight');
        c.addClass('highlight');  
        currCell.parent().removeClass('highlight-rc');
        c.parent().addClass('highlight-rc'); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help.
Sincerely,

Comment: A Table element doesn't have a `cell` (or `cells`) property. It does have a `rows` property, which contains a collection of Rows, which in turn contain a `cells` property, which is a collection of Cells. As you're already using jQuery, then you can make the code much more simply by using DOM traversal methods such as `prev()`, `next()` and `closest()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But then why did it work perfectly when I had the DataTable script on ? Shouldn't it be the same logic ? I tried to solve this by adding table and cells vars but this is meaningless then ?
Could you please be a bit more specific about what I should change in my code please ? My head is full of this at the moment and I can't figure anything anymore haha
Thanks a lot

Comment: Ah, so `table` contains a DataTable instance, not an TableElement object - that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes it did but since I'm trying to remove the DataTable instance (and the script), it does no longer have this instance right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rory help, I've been able to rethink my function and make it work. I'm posting it here if it can help anyone with the same troubles :

```
// Navigate with arrows //
var currCell = $('td').first();
var editing = false;

// User clicks on a cell //
$('td').click(function() {
    currCell = $(this);
    // edit(); //
}); 

// User navigates table using keyboard //
$('#mytable tbody').keydown(function(e) {
    var c = "";
    // Function to make highlight follow the navigation //
    function highlight() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.highlight-rc').forEach(col => col.classList.remove('highlight-rc'));
        currCell.removeClass('highlight');
        var navIndex = $(c).index();
        const columns = document.querySelectorAll(`td:nth-child(${navIndex+1})`);
        columns.forEach(col => {
            col.classList.add('highlight-rc');
        c.addClass('highlight');  
        c.parent().addClass('highlight-rc'); 
        })
    }
```